# regex multiline with diffrent length

Tags: regex

I have a multi line text.

```
Leui Centum 07 Base 9GALLON  
2020-02-10  
1,00 kg  461,90 461,90710201449  
3899104400  
EAN13 7344236003355

Leui Centum 07 Base 9GALLON  
2020-02-10  
1,00 kg  159,62 159,62050223  
3248900000  
EAN13 7358962113386
```

---

Well I´ve tried for a while now to get the last characters behind the second decimal at line 3

If the whole line goes:

```
1,00 kg  159,62 159,62050223
```

`^\d,?[,$].+,..` with regex:
the value I get is

```
1,00 kg  159,62 159,62
```

but my goal is to get the value marked in bold.

1,00 kg 159,62 159,62 **050223**
1,00 kg  461,90 461,90 **710201449**

as you can see the length dont match as the lines in the whole text is digits.
when I try to use `$` I get all the lines besides the first. and I cant figure how to escape to only get the 3:rd line, I cant use `.` becuse the lenght is diffrent. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is very loose see this example https://regex101.com/r/7qVM6W/1
You need to look at the actual requirements for line 3, will it always be in the format you suggest? if so maybe try the following regex with a capture group to grab the final characters.

questions to ask

1. is the value always in the same shape?
2. is it always kg
3. is the value at the end always a number?

https://regex101.com/r/7qVM6W/2

```
^(\d+,?)+\d+ (kg|lb|ton) (\d+,?)+\d+ \d{3},\d{2}(?<VALUE>\d+)
```

the VALUE you're after will be in the final capture group

Comment: Value reference gave me the correct value! Thank you! Not only did you solve the problem you actually give me good insight!

Comment: is it possible to use regex in automation, actually to clean PDFs, I´m a bit new to regex, let´s say we got diffrent suppliers and they send bills in PDFs but diffrent layouts. is it possible for regex to clean the data for all PDFs to get the desierd output?

Comment: That is a much bigger question than the regex one you are originally asking about here.Ii have no experience with doing that, it may be possible, i would recommend asking another question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to achieve this with this simple regex:

```
.*kg.*(\b\d+$)
```

Explanation:
Search for a line that has "kg" in it and take a number that's at the end of the line into a capturing group. Be sure to have **multiline** flag on.

A demo on regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/U9PQ8I/1/

Comment: This is an extreamly loose regex . will match any character so you will match the string "foobar-kg!!!!!?? 12121212121212121212" probably not what you want! see https://regex101.com/r/U9PQ8I/2

Comment: Well I guess the topic starter can decide if that's what he wants or not. Given his data structure, it works just fine and is simple to read. Of course if data structure changes a lot, then he needs a more complicated solution.

Comment: Hi pavel, this one gave me the whole number, reach to the comma, what I want is to exclude it from the second decimal, like from :

**1,00 kg 159,62 159,62050223** I want **050223** and:
**1,00 kg 461,90 461,90710201449** I want **710201449**

the structure is more complicated, but we can leave the whole data structure for now becuse first things first :)

Comment: hey @friend, so you need a number on from two digits after a coma like 1,234567 turns into 4567? Is that correct?

Comment: correct, the regex seemed little bit complex for my knowlage.

Comment: I see that there's a correct answer already, but just for consistency here's my version of it that also works and is a bit simpler: .*kg.*\b.*,\d{2}(\d+$)  (https://regex101.com/r/U9PQ8I/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the fact that **the value just before the one you want is displayed twice**. With this preamption, we can know where to start capturing the value you are looking for!

This can be done by using a capturing group and a reference to this group.

The regex would be `^[\d,]+\s+kg\s+([\d,]+)\s+\1(\d+)\s*$` with the `i` (insensitive) and `m` (`^` and `$` match lines beginning and end).

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/C0PpRG/2

Explanation:

- `^[\d,]+` will match numbers and commas once or more.
- `\s+` for one or more spaces.
- `kg\s+` for the case insensitive `kg` word with some spaces after.
- `([\d,]+)` to capture the first value such as the 461,90 or the 159,62.
- `\1` is the reference to this captured group.
- `(\d+)` is the second group that you are looking for :-)

Comment: This would match the following ",,,,,,,,,,,,      kg  ,,, ,,,12345 " i suppose it depends on the specification of the data file as to is this would ever happen and what should occur if it does

Comment: @Damo Yes, exactly! Well, the best person to know how to write the regex is the one that knows what the data contains!

Comment: true, we are but guessing at the true business requirements